# Project-Prefix.pch file in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode6, pch

In Xcode 6 the .pch file is not created automatically for you anymore. I understand there are steps to create the file on your own. My question is, should the .pch file be added at all?

Did Apple move away from the .pch file completely? Or is there a new convention used to store all #import statements?